# How to know why onStart() is called

Tags: android, android-activity

My question is simple, how can i know if the `onStart()` method got called because my activity got created or because it got started by another activity through an intent?

I guess its not specifically the `onStart()` method but any of the activity lifecycle methods that gets called when creating an activity.    Thanks.

Comment: You can try to use the stack trace: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29

Comment: i want to do something in my activity based on if app is created, and not started from another activty - i don't just want to know  for the knowledge of it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html look at this image, maybe you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate-> onStart-> onResume. Genrally this process is followed when an Activity is Created. If you want to get notified that your Activity is called by an Intent, pass any variable using putExtra from calling activity and then check whether it has some value in getExtra in Called Activity.

Answer (score 0):

use an extra intent for checking whenever your activity got created or got started by another activity by intent :

```
public static final EX_INFO = "from_another";
private boolean isFromAnotherActivity = false;
```

and when you start from another activity by intent, just pass the intent with:

```
intent.putExtra(EX_INFO, true)
```

read the info from your onStart method

```
Intent intent = getExtraIntent();
isFromAnotherActivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(EX_INFO, false);
```